# Function doesn't return properly in recursive function?

Tags: python, function, return

I was trying to write a recursive function that returns the collatz sequence of a number, but the code (shown below) doesn't work. How could this be circumvented and why does this happen?

If I write `print(x)` instead of return x, it can print fine and I can't figure out why it wouldn't be able to return x.

```
def collatz(x):
    if x[-1] == 1:
        return x
    elif x[-1] % 2 == 0:
        collatz(x + [x[-1]/2])
    elif x[-1] % 2 == 1:
        collatz(x + [3*x[-1] + 1])
```

Comment: You return x, but in recursive calls your should also return. Otherwise only innermost call returns x, but the outer ones don't return anything. Basically: `collatz(x +...` -> `return collatz(x +...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return a value from the recursive calls. So each time you call recursively, you're actually returning `None`.

Add a `return` before each of the calls to `collatz`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `return`s for the recursive calls. This is what you need:

```
def collatz(x):
    if x[-1] == 1:
        return x
    elif x[-1] % 2 == 0:
        return collatz(x + [x[-1]/2])
    elif x[-1] % 2 == 1:
        return collatz(x + [3*x[-1] + 1])
```